# How to add alternative user principal name for a new user

Tags: powershell

I am setting up user principal name for new user by below powershell command.

```
Set-ADUser $newUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName
```

but I want to add another user principal name as alternative. Any way to do it??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't have a user a single principal name?

Comment: Already a principal name is there for a particular user. Could you please check that? Use this to check first. `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName`

Comment: Yes, it has one upn already. but the requirement is to add another one as alternate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add multiple records as **UserPrincipalName** attribute.

I belive you are looking for [UPN suffix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc772007(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: How do I add UPN suffix for a particular user?

Comment: Its a domain wide option. You then set UserPrincipalName for particular user.